# How to add new layer to client mapbox map on button click with JS/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mapbox, geojson

### Problem:

I am working on project where I use node.js server that communicate with my spatial DB in PG and my **client uses mapbox** to vizualize map on his side. After hitting a button, the request is send to server, server to psql, psql to server as result query and then through socket.io back to client, where **I want to put my geoJSON / new geometry as new layer on his map after that client buttonclick occurs**. Map on client side in HTML is well working and I can interact with it. I use JS inside of HTML page of my client. From there I need to update mapbox map with new geometry after button click.

### Code sample:

But I tried this code, but this do nothing after button click and will show no errors in devTool Chrome console:

```
    <script>
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'secretToken-I-have-just-for-ilustr--this-is-working';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map', // container id
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v10',
    center: [17.10, 48.14], // starting position on Bratislava
    zoom: 11 // starting zoom
});

// Add zoom and rotation controls to the map.
map.addControl(new mapboxgl.NavigationControl());

// later SOCKET PROCESSING
    
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#buttonRun').click(function(e){

                map.on('load', function () {
                    alert("got HERE") // this is working, alert shows itself
                    map.addLayer({
                        "id": "route",
                        "type": "line",
                        "source": {
                            "type": "geojson",
                            "data": {
                                "type": "Feature",
                                "properties": {},
                                "geometry": {
                                    "type": "LineString",
                                    "coordinates": [
                                        [-122.48369693756104, 37.83381888486939],
                                        [-122.48348236083984, 37.83317489144141],
                                        [-122.48339653015138, 37.83270036637107],
                                        [-122.48356819152832, 37.832056363179625],
                                        [-122.48404026031496, 37.83114119107971],
                                        [-122.48404026031496, 37.83049717427869],
                                        [-122.48348236083984, 37.829920943955045],
                                        [-122.48356819152832, 37.82954808664175],
                                        [-122.48507022857666, 37.82944639795659],
                                        [-122.48610019683838, 37.82880236636284],
                                        [-122.48695850372314, 37.82931081282506],
                                        [-122.48700141906738, 37.83080223556934],
                                        [-122.48751640319824, 37.83168351665737],
                                        [-122.48803138732912, 37.832158048267786],
                                        [-122.48888969421387, 37.83297152392784],
                                        [-122.48987674713133, 37.83263257682617],
                                        [-122.49043464660643, 37.832937629287755],
                                        [-122.49125003814696, 37.832429207817725],
                                        [-122.49163627624512, 37.832564787218985],
                                        [-122.49223709106445, 37.83337825839438],
                                        [-122.49378204345702, 37.83368330777276]
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "layout": {
                            "line-join": "round",
                            "line-cap": "round"
                        },
                        "paint": {
                            "line-color": "#888",
                            "line-width": 8
                        }
                    });
                });

            });
        });
    </script>
```

Even this is not working - even if I set data in click function in a static way, but this data will later change dynamically. If I add that layer out of click event function scope, it is working and layer loads on client map.

### Settings / versions:

- Windows10 Pro - 64-bit
- Google Chrome - Version 69.0.3497.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- Node.js - v10.11.0
- mapbox-gl.js v0.49.0

### Q:

Is there any way how to add layer to mapbox map dynamically, please? And later to remove without page refresh? (I still not found answer, even [here](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/geojson-line/))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution

Okay, I found something I before did not see, concretely [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49967994/mapbox-gl-js-refresh-layer?rq=1).

I better read [documentation](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/animate-a-line/), and it is impossible to setup new layers dynamically, but now it is working as follows / you need to:

1. Out of all scopes define your variables, for example geoJson1, and geoJson2 that you can later edit / fill with function
2. Setup your layer in advance on map with your ID (as in code below) and fill it for example with goeJson1 or with empty []
3. In your on click listener function call this: **map.getSource('data-update').setData(geojson2);**

You just can setup as many layers in advance as you need, and later you can update them.

#### Code result:

```
<script>

    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'token-from-your-registered-account';
    var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map', // container id
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v10',
        center: [17.10, 48.14], // starting position on Bratislava
        zoom: 11 // starting zoom
    });

    var geojson = {
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "features": [{
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "LineString",
                "coordinates": [
                        [-122.48369693756104, 37.83381888486939],
                        [-122.48348236083984, 37.83317489144141],
                        [-122.48339653015138, 37.83270036637107],
                        [-122.48356819152832, 37.832056363179625],
                        [-122.48404026031496, 37.83114119107971]
                    ]
            }
        }]
    };

    var geojson2 = {
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "features": [{
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "LineString",
                "coordinates": [
                        [-122.48369693756104, 37.83381888486939],
                        [-122.48348236083984, 37.83317489144141],
                        [-122.48339653015138, 37.83270036637107],
                        [-122.48356819152832, 37.832056363179625],
                        [-122.48404026031496, 37.83114119107971],
                        [-122.48404026031496, 37.83049717427869],
                        [-122.48348236083984, 37.829920943955045],
                        [-122.48356819152832, 37.82954808664175],
                        [-122.48507022857666, 37.82944639795659],
                        [-122.48610019683838, 37.82880236636284],
                        [-122.48695850372314, 37.82931081282506],
                        [-122.48700141906738, 37.83080223556934],
                        [-122.48751640319824, 37.83168351665737],
                        [-122.48803138732912, 37.832158048267786],
                        [-122.48888969421387, 37.83297152392784],
                        [-122.48987674713133, 37.83263257682617],
                        [-122.49043464660643, 37.832937629287755],
                        [-122.49125003814696, 37.832429207817725],
                        [-122.49163627624512, 37.832564787218985],
                        [-122.49223709106445, 37.83337825839438],
                        [-122.49378204345702, 37.83368330777276]
                    ]
            }
        }]
    };

    map.on('load', function () {
        map.addLayer({
            "id": "data-update",
            "type": "line",
            "source": {
                "type": "geojson",
                "data": geojson // your previously defined variable
            },
            "layout": {
                "line-join": "round",
                "line-cap": "round"
            },
            "paint": {
                "line-color": "#888",
                "line-width": 8
            }
        });
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#buttonRun').click(function(e){
             map.getSource('data-update').setData(geojson2);
        });
    });
    
</script>
```